# Plotly express line chart not accepting keywords from documentation

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, analytics, plotly-dash

Trying to create a dash web app, where I set markers to custom colors.

```
# For web app visualization

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

figure=px.line(data_frame=sales_df, x="Month", y="Sales", markers=True, color ="Color")

app.layout=html.Div([
    #Title or analysis
    html.H1("Graph Analysis with brand"),
    #Create dropdown of all unique brands to filter vy
    dcc.Dropdown(id="brand-choice", options=[{"label":x, "value":x} for x in sales_df.Brand.unique()],
                value="some_brand"),
    dcc.Graph(id="graph-analysis", figure=figure )
])

@app.callback(
Output(component_id = "graph-analysis", component_property = "figure"),
Input(component_id = "brand-choice", component_property = "value")
)
def interactive_graphing(brand_value):
    dff = sales_df[sales_df.Brand == brand_value]
    fig=px.line(data_frame=dff, x="Month", y="Sales", markers=True, color ="Color")
    return fig

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

But getting thrown the error "line() got an unexpected keyword argument 'markers" despite documentation showing markers is a keyword argument (https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line)

Already ensured plotly version is 5.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I think the situation is that the definition name of the graph is not unified to figure, so it cannot be displayed.

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

figure=px.line(data_frame=sales_df, x="Month", y="Sales", markers=True, color ="Color")

app.layout=html.Div([
    #Title or analysis
    html.H1("Graph Analysis with brand"),
    #Create dropdown of all unique brands to filter vy
    dcc.Dropdown(id="brand-choice", options=[{"label":x, "value":x} for x in sales_df.Brand.unique()],
                value="some_brand"),
    dcc.Graph(id="graph-analysis", figure=figure )
])

@app.callback(
Output(component_id = "graph-analysis", component_property = "figure"),
Input(component_id = "brand-choice", component_property = "value")
)
def interactive_graphing(brand_value):
    dff = sales_df[sales_df.Brand == brand_value]
    figure = px.line(data_frame=dff, x="Month", y="Sales", markers=True, color ="Color") # update fig ->figure
    return figure # fig->figure

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run_server()
```